# Reverse grep to get the last couple of occurrences in a file

Tags: grep

Say I want to grab the last 5 
mentions of cron in `/var/log/syslog.log` looking over the grep manual it seems like I can't get grep to search in reverse. I can however grab the most recent occurrences.

```
grep cron -m 5 /var/log/syslog
```

Is there a reverse grep command I can use? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following the usual unix philosophy of combining tools: use `grep` to search, and `tail` to return the last part of the file.

```
grep cron /var/log/syslog | tail -n 5
```

Comment: It would be faster to reverse the order if you know that the content you are interested in is within the last X lines.  tail -n 100 < /var/log/syslog |grep cron

Comment: Note this does not actually reverse the order, it just limits the grep to the bottom X lines. May or may not serve the purpose.

Answer (score 17):

What about piping to `tac`?

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tac.htm

```
tac  /var/log/syslog | grep cron -m 5
```

Comment: You need a second tac in the end, to reconstruct the original order, no `tac  /var/log/syslog | grep cron -m 5 | tac`? Tacatac ... :)

Comment: But isn't reverse order part of the request? Taaaac ^^

Comment: Ah, maybe! I understood the reverse-part only as searching for the last ones.